# Flutter why when I return to my original page the build runs again?

Tags: android, flutter, navigation, arguments

why on flutter when I call another page using the

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'namePage', arguments: varHello);
```

and in my page called namePage I get the argument varHello something like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {   
   final aux = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
  }
```

why when I go back to the original page the namePage build is sent to call again?
for explample if I put print in the build

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {  
   print("hello world"); 
   final aux = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
  }
```

when I go to the namePage page on the consol print "hello world"

but when I go back to the previous page (where I sent to call the name page) the console prints again the "hello world"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Flutter teams's reply. 
`Pages on Navigator stack rebuild when a new page is pushed`
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11655#issuecomment-348287396

This is working as intended. In general, you should assume that all widgets can rebuild at any time, that they don't is mostly just an optimisation.

In particular, routes will rebuild because their navigator state has changed so they might need to update how they draw back buttons and the like.

Comment: Do You know how I can eliminate this efect? Because I call a API when de second page initialice, but when I pop this page I calle the API again and I don't want to do this D:

Comment: Need to reproduce your case. Could you provide reproduce code and post to new question. thanks.